# Is there a way to get the HTTP status code in angular with retry using of rxjs operators?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

```
getRequest(url : string,retryCount = 2) {
    return new Observable(response => {
     return this.http.get<any>(url)
     .pipe(
        retryWhen((error) => {
          return error.pipe(
            concatMap((e, i) => {
              if (i >= retryCount) {
                return throwError({ ...e, retryCount });
              }
              return of(e).pipe(delay(2000));
            })
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        response.next(data);
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              response.next() //expected 404 ,500 and so on
          });
      });
  }

getRequest(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/postss).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      });
```

Above code must return error codes on error. the above url does not exist and must get 404 on 2 retries.what changes are needed to get those error codes?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `response.next() //expected 404 ,500 and so on` with `err.status // expected ...` ?

Comment: when you print err what is it that you get?

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve status code in retryWhen operator like this :

```javascript
getRequest(url: string, retryCount = 2) {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => i < retryCount ? timer(2000) : throwError(error)
      )
    ))
  );
}

getRequest('api').subscribe(
  () => { }, // success
  error => console.log(error.status)
);
```

In the code above, within the `retryWhen` operator, we catch the error and we retry the request with 2 second of delay 2 times like you are doing.

Then, we throw the error and we deal with it inside the error function of the subscribe call.

We can get the status by retrieving the `status` property from the incoming error.

I hope I answered your question :)